# Get the object instance from a LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to pass an instance of a class to a method using an `Expression<T>` and retrieve the instance from within the method:

```cs
public class MyOb
{
    public void Receive(Expression<Func<Item>> item)
    {
        // Here I would like to get item as Item
        // Have tried various things such as
        var x = ((MemberExpression)(item.Body)).Member;
        
        int y = x.IntProp  // should be 123.
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public int IntProp { get; set; } = 123;
}

MyOb mo = new();
Item myItem = new();
mo.Receive(() => myItem);
```

Comment: What is `MyOb`?

Comment: @GuruStron Just a class which wants to deal with objects as expressions.

Comment: Does it inherit from `Item` otherwise your code should not compile.

Comment: @GuruStron Ah, Doh. I've edited the sample. Error writing the example.

Comment: For me it looks like you are trying to apply most high end technologies to solve simple real life situation. Think twice the: do you really need expressions because you would like to try them or because you really need them?

Comment: @RemigijusPankevičius Wise words, thanks. My question was driven by a desire to understand a bit more about expressions and see how far I could go in writing a fluent API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would not be that easy because the compiler will generate a special class to handle closure which will store the value of the local variable (`myItem`). Something like this should do the trick:

```
public static void Receive(Expression<Func<Item>> item)
{
    if (item.Body is MemberExpression { Expression: ConstantExpression constE })
    {
        var itemValue = constE.Type.GetFields()
            .Where(fi => fi.FieldType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(Item)))
            .Single() // possibly proper validation message if multiple found
            .GetValue(constE.Value);
        var intProp = ((Item)itemValue).IntProp; // your value
        Console.WriteLine(intProp); // will print 123 for your code
    }
}
```